# Having trouble excluding by case statement in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a list that only shows NFL players from the SEC East and SEC West football conferences. I used a case statement to label each conference, but would like to exclude non-SEC teams. I know I could just do "where collegeName in() and then list all SEC schools, but I'd like to be more efficient if possible. What would you guys do? Here is what I tried (I got an "unrecognized name, conference" error at 11:7):

```
Select collegeName, 
CASE 
When collegeName in('Georgia','Missouri','Tennessee','Kentucky','Florida','South Carolina','Vanderbuilt')
then 'SEC EAST'
When collegeName in ('Alabama','Mississippi','Louisiana State','Texas A&M','Auburn','Mississippi State','Arkansas')
then 'SEC WEST'
ELSE 'Not in the SEC'
END AS Conference,
COUNT(position) as Number_of_Players
From NFL.Players
where Conference not in('Not in the SEC')
group by collegeName
```

Comment: I’d start by creating table(s) that held Conference information and the relationship between Teams and their Conference

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE SEC_EAST DEFAULT ['Georgia','Missouri','Tennessee','Kentucky','Florida','South Carolina','Vanderbuilt'];

DECLARE SEC_WEST DEFAULT ['Alabama','Mississippi','Louisiana State','Texas A&M','Auburn','Mississippi State','Arkansas'];

SELECT 
   collegeName, 
   CASE 
      when collegeName in unnest(SEC_EAST)
      then 'SEC EAST'
      when collegeName in unnest(SEC_WEST)
      then 'SEC WEST'
      else 'Not in the SEC'
   END AS Conference,
   COUNT(position) as Number_of_Players
FROM 
   NFL.Players
WHERE 
   collegeName in unnest(ARRAY_CONCAT(SEC_EAST, SEC_WEST))
GROUP BY 
   collegeName
;
```

I think you can streamline your query by using variables/arrays.

`unnest()` turns arrays into relations/tables that you can access with the `in` operator.

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` after the `GROUP BY` allows you to filter the results based on the *result* of the `GROUP BY`.

Since Conference does not exist as an input field, you cannot specify it in the `WHERE` clause.

`HAVING` allows you to filter on that resulting dataset where the field now exists e.g. `HAVING COUNT(*) >5`, `HAVING Conference = ...` etc. Use it like a `WHERE` clause on the result of the `GROUP BY`.

```
Select 
  collegeName, 
  CASE 
    WHEN collegeName in ('Georgia','Missouri','Tennessee','Kentucky','Florida','South Carolina','Vanderbuilt') THEN 'SEC EAST'
    WHEN collegeName IN ('Alabama','Mississippi','Louisiana State','Texas A&M','Auburn','Mississippi State','Arkansas') THEN 'SEC WEST'
    ELSE 'Not in the SEC'
  END AS Conference,
  COUNT(position) as Number_of_Players
FROM NFL.Players
GROUP BY 1,2 --2 = alias for the CASE statement line
HAVING Conference <> 'Not in the SEC'
```

[Having in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#having_clause)

Comment: Thank you guys! Don't know why I didn't try a CTE in the first place. I'll experiment with arrays as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution will be to use CTE

Ex:

```
with popuplate_conference_details as (
Select collegeName, 
CASE 
When collegeName in('Georgia','Missouri','Tennessee','Kentucky','Florida','South Carolina','Vanderbuilt')
then 'SEC EAST'
When collegeName in ('Alabama','Mississippi','Louisiana State','Texas A&M','Auburn','Mississippi State','Arkansas')
then 'SEC WEST'
ELSE 'Not in the SEC'
END AS Conference,
COUNT(position) as Number_of_Players
From NFL.Players
group by collegeName
)

select * from popuplate_conference_details
where Conference not in('Not in the SEC')
```